# Set favorite question tab

Tags: discussion, tags, new-nav

Whenever I go to the home page of meta (I'm pretty sure this is the same for other sites), I automatically go on the "Need answers" tab. I usually come to meta to look at interesting questions, not answer them. I think I should be able to set which tab I automatically go on when I log on to the site.

> [image: pic]
>
> (I want to go on the popular tag)

This is very annoying when I go to a question, finish looking at it, click to the questions tag, and have to click the popular tag again.

I just want your thoughts about this suggestion!